# python opencv warpAffine applied to stack of images fails

Tags: python, image, opencv, rotation

I have a stack of 500 images, each with dimensions (466, 1012). The whole thing is stored in a numpy array which therefore has dimensions (466, 1012, 500).

I would like to rotate each image by 5 degrees using warpAffine in opencv. I initially used a for loop to apply the function to each of the 500 images one at a time and that worked fine. But then I found it worked 10x faster to just apply warpAffine to the whole array. I.e. I did something like this:

```
import cv2

angle = 5 # I want to rotate each image by 5 degrees
height, width = im.shape[:2] # im has shape (466, 1012, 500)
image_center = (width/2, height/2) # rotate about the image centre

rotationMat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.) 
rotatedMat = cv2.warpAffine(im, rotationMat,(466, 1012))
```

Then I tried to do the same thing on a stack of 600 images and it didn't work. It gave the error:
error: OpenCV(4.2.0) ..\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:2594: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0 in function 'cv::warpAffine'

In fact it stops working at a stack size of 512.

I could go back to using the for loop but I have huge amounts of data to process so the 10x time saving would be very useful. Is there a way to make it work? Also I just interested in why it doesn't work... I can't figure it out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: "In fact it stops working at a stack size of 512." -- Yes, that's the limit of how many channels a `cv::Mat` can hold. Just process it in chunks of at most 512 channels.

Comment: Ah ok that would explain it! Thanks!